# How i add my foreign key on sql

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

I already have P1_ART AND P1_DEGREE AND P1_ARTIST TABLES, BUT I want to add foreign keys to my P1_ARTIST table as follows

```
Alter table P1_ARTIST
ADD CONSTRAINT ARTIST_ART_FK FOREIGN KEY(ART_ID) REFERENCES P1_ART(ART_ID);
Alter table P1_ARTIST
ADD CONSTRAINT ARTIST_DEGREE_FK FOREIGN KEY(DEGREE_ID) REFERENCES P1_DEGREE(DEGREE_ID);
```

I still receiving errors as

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ART_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DEGREE_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Do you have ART_ID column in both P1_ARTIST and P1_ART tables? Do you have DEGREE_ID column in both P1_ARTIST and P1_DEGREE tables?

Comment: YES, I ALREADY HAVE THAT